# Wait for mongo writes before returning from a find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I want a `store` js object that manages a mongodb collection and behaves like that:

```
store.insert(thing); // called from a pubsub system that don't wait the insert to finish

store.get(); // returns a promise that resolves to the things in the collection
// even if called immediately after insert it must contain the last thing inserted
```

I implemented it manually like that:

```
let inserts = 0;
let afterInserts = [];

const checkInsertsFinished = () => {
  if (inserts === 0) {
    afterInserts.forEach(resolve => resolve());
    afterInserts = [];
  }
};

const decrementInserts = () => {
  inserts -= 1;
  checkInsertsFinished();
};

const insertsFinished = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    afterInserts.push(resolve);
    checkInsertsFinished();
  });

const insert = (thing) => {
  inserts += 1;
  db.collection('mycollection').insertOne(thing).then(decrementInserts);
};

const get = async () => {
  await insertsFinished(); // if there are inserts happening, wait for them to finish
  return db.collection('mycollection').find({}).toArray();
};

return { insert, get };
```

I suppose that there are more standard ways to accomplish this but I miss the vocabulary to find libs or built-in features... How would you do that?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult You could use the id of the inserted document, if the id of latest insert is not latest of get you're missing some documents and try to recursively call get again. Depends on the amount of documents you expect though, if it's sorted by id it should be performant.

Comment: I think that it won't work: if I call `insert` then immediately call `get`, the `find` can return faster than the `insertOne` and I wont compare it with the id resulting from the previous insert.

Comment: updated the answer, lots of bugs in there but think this should do it. The point is that `insert` can never be called while it's running but can be called while you're doing `db.collection('mycollection').find({}).toArray(` so you can set local start to shared startGetting and check referential equality later (see if `insert` de-referenced startGetting) In JS `{}!=={}`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded, none of code you write can be run at the same time on multiple threads so you should be able to do it this way:

```
let inserting = Promise.resolve(),
startGetting={};

const insert = (thing) => {
  startGetting={};//de-reference startGetting
  inserting = db.collection('mycollection').insertOne(thing)
  return inserting;
};

const get = () => {
  const rec = () =>
    inserting.then(
      _ =>
        new Promise(
          (resolve,reject)=>{
            //the next op is truely async (although I wonder why no promise),
            //  someone can insert while this is completing
            const start=startGetting;
            db.collection('mycollection').find({}).toArray(
              (err,results)=>
                err
                  ? reject(err)
                  //inserting could have been set to tby the time
                  //  this completed (in theory) so use startGetting reference equality
                  : startGetting === start
                    ? resolve(results)//while getting nobody inserted
                    : resolve(rec())
          )
        })
    );
  return rec();
};

return { insert, get };
```